# RC File info not working across different machines

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have a Visual C++ MFC app.  When I update the RC file menus via resource editor, sometimes it isn't reflected when I run the app.  Other times, the updated menus work on the development machine, but not on other machines.  Note: the other machines had a previous version of the software installed.  I simply copied and pasted the release folder over from one machine to another.  Using the Wix installer we use to install everything (AFTER UNINSTALLING FROM CONTROL PANEL) doesn't seem to work either.  What I missing?  How do I get my menus to behave correctly?  Why do things work on some PCs and not on others?

Comment: Are you sure the new version is correctly installed on the machine where you still get the old menu? Are you sure the problem is not in the build process?

Comment: @MichaelWalz All other changes work.  Its just the RC file menus that act up.  Its not the build process.  Thanks though.

Comment: Try deleting the .aps and .res files that correspond to your .rc file before building your solution. If those files are out of sync with the .rc file, these types of problems may occur.

Comment: @rrirower I tried that.  It helps, but it doesn't solve all the issues, especially when moving across machines.  Thoughts?

Comment: Are you building resource-only dlls?  Or, are the resources bound to the executable?

Comment: @rrirower That I do not know.  How do I check?

Comment: Resource-only dlls are typically used to internationalization.  the segregate the application resources into their own dll.  If you're not sure, you probably are not using them.

Comment: @rrirower We did use to support multiple languages with language "plug-in" dlls.  It sounds to me like those DLLs are suspect.  Might you able to further assist?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139183/discussion-between-dan-g-and-rrirower).